# How to view CHM files?

Tags: software-recommendation

How to view [CHM files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`chmsee` is no longer available in Ubuntu, as it is no longer being maintained. Here is the announcement on the project site:

> ChmSee is no longer maintained.
>
> ChmSee is not being developed anymore.
>
> I haven't read CHM documents more than a year, new and updated IT books are pdfs or epubs, so it's the right time to end this chm viewer.

---

### ChmSee

[image]

[https://code.google.com/p/chmsee/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150922104444/http://code.google.com/p/chmsee/)

```
sudo apt-get install chmsee
```

Comment: Thanks. Note: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/chmsee gives "You don't seem to be running Ubuntu" from Ubuntu 10.04/Chrome.

Comment: Unable to locate package chmsee on Ubuntu 14.04 :(

Comment: @borjacampina, HOW to install it in ubutnu 14.04?

Comment: @shgnInc http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/trusty/apps/getdeb/chmsee Download 32-bit or 64-bit deb file depend on arch.. install it using sudo dbpg -i <filename>

Comment: I has been using chmsee for many time, but is no more mantained... See https://code.google.com/p/chmsee/

Answer (score 82):

### xChm Viewer

Install the xChm Viewer for viewing CHM files:

```
sudo apt-get install xchm
```

[image]

Comment: The search function doesn't work for me.

Comment: It seems xchm doesn't support multi-bytes characters. I encountered an error when open a .chm document which contains multi-bytes characters: `../src/common/unichar.cpp(65): assert "Assert failure" failed in ToHi8bit(): character cannot be converted to single byte`

Answer (score 33):

```
apt-cache --names-only search chm
```

gives several results.

Comment: +1 for helping people to find their own answers. But a more verbose answer, explaining the results would be better.

Comment: +1 for teaching ppl how to fish!

Answer (score 19):

### [kchmViewer](http://www.ulduzsoft.com/linux/kchmviewer/) [image: Install kchmviewer]

> The main advantage of kchmviewer is the best support for non-English languages. Unlike other viewers, kchmviewer in most cases is able to correctly detect the chm file encoding and show it. It correctly shows the index and table of context in Russian, Spanish, Romanian, Korean, Chinese and Arabic help files, and with new search engine is able to search in any chm file no matter what language it is written.

[image: kchmviewer]

Comment: This worked for me while the others didn't.

Answer (score 9):

I like the reader that comes with wine! (hh.exe?)

Open hh.exe that comes with wine and browse for your CHM file from it, or supply it as a command line argument:

`$ wine /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine-development/fakedlls/hh.exe WindowsHalp.chm`

Answer (score 8):

## Use browser extensions

What could be better than a *web-browser* to view *web-pages*?

[**CHMFox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chmfox/) is an excellent CHM file reader. It is much better than all the third party programs that others are suggesting, which are mostly lacking many web-browser capabilities that Firefox and alike have.

I initially suggested the [CHM reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/chm-reader/) extension for Firefox, but it isn't actively maintained anymore.

Comment: There is a new firefox add-on called ChmFox 1.2. Supposed to be a replacement for the old CHM reader project. you can find it at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chmfox/

Comment: Cannot install CHM reader, but ChmFox is good.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I have installed the add-on (ChmFox) but firefox doesn't open the file, it just tries to re-download it from the local storage. Would you please suggest what should I do to fix this?

Comment: The link is broken. Currently, there's no CHMFox extension in Firefox Add-ons. I think it has been removed.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative, since the CHM format is not very popular you can convert it to PDF using `chm2pdf`:

```
sudo apt-get install chm2pdf
chm2pdf --webpage your.chm
```

This will produce a `your.pdf` file. As an alternative you can use the `--book` or `--continuous` options instead of `--webpage`; more info here http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-convert-chm-files-into-pdf-files-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 2):

Also a plugin called CHM Reader exists for Firefox.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3235/

Comment: here https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3235/

Answer (score 2):

`extract_chmLib` does a very good job of converting *chm* (compiled html) files into *htm* format. It is in the Ubuntu repository in the package `libchm-bin`.

*extract_chmLib* maintains the full functionality of the original.. However, I did need to rename files to lowercase, for one .chm (becaue `chm` is a Windows format which is not case-sensitive like Linux),  but the overall result is ideal for me...

Here are a couple of links...

- [How to convert CHM files under Linux (The Mad Philosopher)](http://madphilosopher.ca/2006/09/how-to-convert-chm-files-under-linux/)
- [Convert chm to pdf or MS word or open office word processor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14750/convert-chm-to-pdf-or-ms-word-or-open-office-word-processor)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Firefox extension(s), there's a neat Chrome app called [Chumium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chumium-chm-file-reader/ihfoglidabnbmgpfibclmibdpgemobgi) that does the job.

Answer (score 2):

[Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/about) is a library manager that can read all sorts of book formats, CHM included.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of CHM readers. You can find them in Software Center. Just type `chm`.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu Software Center you can do a search for "chm" (no quotes) and find some decent chm viewers.

However, while using them, I'm always missing the scaling features in firefox (to make everything bigger - not just fonts).

Therefore, my favorite CHM viewer is Firefox itself via the [ChmFox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/chmfox/).

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install kchmviewer
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 18.04 as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer GnoCHM.

Comment: gnochm isn't available in maverick 10.10

Comment: why gnochm is any more on Ubuntu repository?

Answer (score 0):

By default ubuntu doesn't provide any chm reader.

If you have installed `wine`, then by default it provides one package named `hh`.

1. Right click on file.
2. Open with wine
3. Just select hh as default option it shows and select

Answer (score 0):

[Sumatra PDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/download-free-pdf-viewer) can display `.chm` files also. Although, **Sumatra PDF** is a Windows program, you can just download the "portable version" and run it under [Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).