# Convert chm to pdf or MS word or open office word processor?

Tags: pdf, file-format, convert

Is it possible to convert `chm` files to `pdf` or word in GUI fashion?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a way to do it completely on the graphical user interface, but this isn't too bad:

1. First, you'll need to install [**libchm-bin** [image: Install libchm-bin]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libchm-bin)
   (click to install).
2. Then, open a Terminal and type

   ```
   extract_chmLib your_file.chm .
   ```

   (Mind the full stop at the end, it
   represents the current directory) 
   This will output a *HTML* file from
   the chm file.
3. You can now open up the HTML file
   with Firefox and select **Print**,
   which will allow you to print it to
   a file, outputting a PDF. Go to
   "Options" to get rid the margin
   notes that firefox will put into the
   output.

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

Calibre which can be installed from the software center has a .chm conversion input plugin, it also has a .pdf conversion output plugin so in theory it is supposed to be able to do what you want, may not be perfect though.

Another GUI option, though painstaking, is to install the nice .chm viewer called chmsee, this can be installed from software center as well, you then open the file with chmsee and you can copy and paste to OpenOffice.org Writer then save to .doc or export to .pdf

For me I just use the command line tool chm2pdf which gives fairly good results, this method uses htmldoc as a helper application.

Answer (score 2):

1. chm2pdf
2. calibre

Both in the repos